# Reading in data with header separators different from delimiters

Tags: r

```
StateNonfiscal <- read.table("State_Nonfiscal_1314.txt", header=TRUE, 
sep = ",", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

This is what I have so far, I'm using the flat file from 2013-2014 found [here](https://nces.ed.gov/ccd/pubagency.asp).

Structure is 43 x 1

Comment: All the files I've opened in that website use `tab` separator. Use `sep="\t"`

Answer (score 0):

like that:

```
StateNonfiscal <- read.table("State_Nonfiscal_1314.txt", header=TRUE, 
sep="\t", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```